# menu button in header of tabBarNavigation: can't call this.props.navigation.openDrawer();

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I had custom header of tabBarNavigation like this:

```
import HeaderTab from './HeaderTab/HeaderTab';

  TabNavigator: {
    screen: TabNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: (
    <HeaderTab/>

  ),
    }
  },
```

code of `HeaderTab` component :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import Styles from './Styles';
import {withTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

export class HeaderTab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      test:  i18n.dir(),

    }
  }
  render() {
    const { t, i18n } = this.props;

    return (


                <View style={Styles.container}>

                  <View style={Styles.header}>
                    <View style={Styles.ic1Container}>
                      <TouchableOpacity style={Styles.buttonHeaderStyle}>
                        <IconII name="ios-arrow-back"/>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                      <TouchableOpacity
                      style={Styles.buttonHeaderStyle}
                      onPress={() => **this.props.navigation.openDrawer()**}>
                        <IconAD name="menuunfold"/>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                    <View style={Styles.ic2Container}>
                      <TouchableOpacity style={Styles.buttonHeaderStyle}>
                        <IconAD  name="camerao"/>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <View style={Styles.infosMt}>
                   {...}
                  </View>
             </View>
    );
  }
}
export default withTranslation(['HeaderTab', 'common'], { wait: true })(HeaderTab);
```

I want to open drawer like I do in every other views : `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()` but I have an error this.props.navigation undefined, so I pass it from props :

```
  TabNavigator: {
    screen: TabNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: (
    <HeaderTab navigation = {this.props.navigation}/>
  ),
    }
  },
```

in Header component :

```
  render() {
    const { t, i18n } = this.props;
    const navigation = this.props.navigation;
    {... some code}
                      <TouchableOpacity
                      style={Styles.buttonHeaderStyle}
                      onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
                        <IconAD name="menuunfold"/>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

I have an error when I refresh the app: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')`

*PS1. `Header` component is in `TabBarNavigation` that is also in a `stackNavigation`*
*PS2. `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()` works in all screens in `stackNavigation`*

Answer (score 0):

> Header component is in TabBarNavigation that is also in a stackNavigation
>
> this.props.navigation.openDrawer() works in all screens in stackNavigation

Then pass `this.props.navigation` from `stackNavigation` to `TabBarNavigation` to `Header`

Comment: but how can I pass it tabBarNavigation from stackNavigation ? I pass it from stackNavigation directly to Header component, see my first code, it is in StackNavigation

Comment: You say that the `TabBarNavigation` component is called in the render method of your `StackNavigation` component? And calling `this.props.navigation` in the `StackNavigation` component does NOT return `undefined`? Then when you call the `TabBarNavigation` component, just pass navigation as props, or 
`<TabBarNavigation navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

Comment: no I dont call tabBarNavigation like a component !! I call it like thhis :    TabNavigator: {
    screen: TabNavigator,
  }, ___ see my answer in this post for root navigation

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a drawer navigator to do so and then add it to your root navigator. You can customize the side navgition by adding a custom component `contentComponent: SideMenu`

```
import React from 'react'
import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator'
import AboutUs from '../../views/Static/About'
import SideMenu from '../../components/SideMenu'

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {screen: AppNavigator},
    AboutUs: {screen: AboutUs},
  },
  {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.83
  }
)

DrawerNavigator.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  header: null
})

export default DrawerNavigator
```

Now you can add this Drawer Navigator in the root navigator as:

```
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import LoginNavigator from './LoginNavigator'
import DrawerNavigator from './DrawerNavigator'

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {screen: LoginNavigator},
    Drawer: {screen: DrawerNavigator}
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Drawer'
  }
)

export default createAppContainer(RootStack)
```

Now on presing the `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()` you will be able to open the DrawerNavigator.

Comment: I have already create a drawer navigator . stackNavigation is in draweNnavigator

Comment: Can you just add your root navigation part?

Comment: it is in 'answer' for more details ! i can't put it here in comment

Answer (score 0):

root navigation:
I have 4 navigation:
authFlowNavigation: `switchNavigator`
DrawerNavigation: `drawerNavigator`
MainStackNavigation: `stackNavigator`
TabBarNavigation: `tabBarNavigator`

code of switchNavigation (Root navigation):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import DrawerNavigation from './DrawerNavigation';
import MainNavigation from './MainStackNavigation';
import ActNavigation from './ActivationStackNavigation';
import TabBarNav from './TabBarNavigation';


const AuthFlowNavigation = createSwitchNavigator({
  SplashBOX: SplashScreen,
  Drawer: DrawerNavigation,
  ActBOX: ActNavigation,
  MainBOX: MainNavigation,
  TabBarNav: TabBarNav,
})

export default createAppContainer(AuthFlowNavigation)
```

code of drawer navigation:

```
imports...
var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({

      MainStack: {
        screen: MainStackNavigation,
      },
  },
  {
    drawerWidth: width*0.83,
    contentComponent: props =>
    {
      return(<DrawerComponent {...props}/>)
    },
    drawerPosition: 'left',
  },

  );
export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigation)
```

ans stackNavigation contain tabBarNavigation !

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution for that! Take a look at the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/) ...

Install the package "**@react-navigation/native**", import "**useNavigation**" and instantiate it inside its default function just like I did in the code below ...

```js
...
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'; //imported here
...

export default function Header() {
  const navigation = useNavigation(); //declared here
  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          backgroundColor: '#000',
          paddingHorizontal: 20,
        }}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} size={30} color="#FFF" onPress={() => { navigation.openDrawer(); }} /> //used here to open the menu drawer
...
```